# Android screen resolution universal in Unity

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Android development, I have a simple game that I have tested on a couple of devices. On my Unity screen and on one of the Android devices everything is as normal. However, when I test on other device the game is half way off the screen?! How do I go about making the game truly universal for every screen resolution?

Comment: You need to show as much as possible, for us to be able to help.... add code, layout, manifest, etc.... are you using what to display the screen? an Activity?

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas Scalar](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) is your solution. The Canvas Scaler component is used for controlling the overall scale and pixel density of UI elements in the Canvas. This scaling affects everything under the Canvas, including font sizes and image borders.

If a Canvas is set to ‘Screen Space - Overlay’ or ‘Screen Space - Camera’, then the Canvas Scaler UI Scale Mode can be set to Constant Pixel Size, Scale With Screen Size, or Constant Physical Size.

This youtube video outlines how to do it:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkfhxuNr9Es
```

Comment: Thank you I'll have a  look at the YouTube video for answers :) It would have taken me ages to break down the game which is why I didn't. I just wanted to know if it was a common problem across devices and if I need to set different apks for different devices.